# I want to handle exception generate from fcm if device token no longer valid

Tags: laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging

I face the issue that if device no longer exists the fcm response containing the error like that

```
{
    "message": "Client error: `POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/internationalfriendspusher/messages:send'resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:\n{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 
404,\n    \"message\": \"Requested entity was not found.\",\n    \"status\": 
\"NOT_FOUND\",\n    \"detail (truncated...)\n",
    "exception": "Kreait\\Firebase\\Exception\\Messaging\\NotFound",
    "file": "/var/www/vhosts/lvps87-230-85- 
   233.dedicated.hosteurope.de/pusherang/MainApp/vendor/kreait/firebase- 
   php/src/Firebase/Exception/MessagingException.php"
}
```

i actually send bulk notification having device ids inside an array and loop through it when any device id to the corresponding token were no longer exist it break my code so i want to handle that and continue to the next device id

my request payload

```
{
    "message": {
    "content":"My Test notification",
    "content_available":"zXCzCzDXs",
    "message_url":"www.example.com",
    "priority":"dfgdfgfd",
    "title":"Test"
    },
    "device_ids":[
    "4706277e9565496",
    "f02f1f4558206539"
    ]
}
```

code

```
foreach($input['device_ids'] as $deviceId)
{
    $pusher = Push::where('device_id' , $deviceId )
                       ->where('push_enable' , 'true')
                       ->first();
    if($pusher)
    {
         if(strtolower($pusher->push_enable)  == "true")
         {
             $deviceToken = $pusher->registration_id;

             $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $deviceToken);

             $title = $input['message']['title'];
             $body = $input['message']['content'];

             $notification = Notification::fromArray([
                   'title' => $title,
                   'body' => $body
             ]);

             $message = $message->withNotification($notification);

             try 
             {
                 // Here notification send to device and here my code breaks if device token not validate or user install app
                 $this->messaging->send($message));     
                 $device = new Device;
                 $device->deviceId = $deviceId;
                 $device->title = $title;
                 $device->content = $body;
                 $device->message_url = $input['message']['message_url'];
                 $device->priority = $input['message']['priority'];
                 $device->content_available = $input['message']['content_available'];
                 $status = $device->save();
                 if($status)
                 {
                    continue;
                 }                                    
            }
            catch(Exception $e) 
           {
              echo "Permission denied for Device: ".$deviceId." having token ".$deviceToken." from Firebase";
                                  continue;
           }
      }
      else
      {
        continue;
      }                                
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Device having id ".$deviceId." were not found";
     continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look into try/catch. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors

Comment: my send method already inside try catch block its not a solution

Comment: Sure it is. You can put a try/catch within another try/catch without issues. Wrap *each* send in one, and you can log failures and continue onwards.

Comment: I also provide my code. so can you identify where i put try catch block

Comment: I'd bet your issue is the namespacing of `catch(Exception $e)` - it's probably only catching something like `App\Http\Controllers\YourController\Exception` (which doesn't exist). Try `catch(\Exception $e)` - note the leading \ - or put `use Exception;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Yes you r right you solved by issue

Comment: Cool, I've added an answer reflecting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there - this is a namespacing issue.

`catch(Exception $e)`, within a namespaced file (i.e. there's `namespace App\Foo\Bar` up the top of the file), doesn't catch much - it's namespaced too, so you'd only be catching `App\Foo\Bar\Exception`.

Putting a `use Exception` alias at the top of the file will tell PHP to use the *root* Exception rather than a namespaced one.

Alternatively, `catch(\Exception $e)`, with the leading \, will do the same thing.

Side note: You can catch *specific* exceptions in the same way, i.e.:

```
catch(\Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Messaging\NotFound $e)
```